# Facebook ASP.net web app iframe login?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Could some kind soul please tell me the correct way to ensure and login a facebook user using the facebook-c#-sdk in a C# web application. Thanking you.

Comment: What type of web app? MVC, Web Forms?
Also what type of FBApp? Canvas or Connect?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutrial for that  http://codethatworkedforme.blogspot.com/2011/08/facebook-connect.html
and demo of http://codethatworkedforme.blogspot.com/2011/09/facebook-connect-demo.html